# React Suspense not working with useEffect/setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, react-suspense

I have suspense like this in the App file

```
<Suspense fallback={<DelayedFallback />}>
```

Then I have an useEffect/setTimeOut:

```
const DelayedFallback = () => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setLoaded(true), 5000);
  }, []);

  return <> {!loaded && <Loading />} </>;
};

export default DelayedFallback;
```

The purpose is the client wants people who visit the website to watch their video.

Suspense is not respecting this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `Suspense` is not mean for that, check the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#suspense

Comment: Sounds like you should do all that within the component itself rather than using suspense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is to delay the rendering of a component for an arbitrary amount of time you could simply do something like:

```
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setIsLoaded(true);
  }, 5000);
});

if (!isLoaded) return <Loading />;

return <MyComponent />;
```

If you are using `<video>` you could use the [`ended` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) instead of a `setTimeout`.

At the moment, `Suspense` is only meant for lazy loading React components.

Comment: Thank you for this! This makes total sense. 

I am working on a 3JS app that has a gif that needs to be run at the beginning.Not sure if the ended event will work as it is a gif.

But this solution worked. 

I will just apply Suspense to individual components  as they are indeed lazy.